# Conditional converting data in dataframe in r

Tags: r

I am trying to change my data frame (names icorr) based on conditions. I want to do this for all the items in the dataframe. I'm quite new to r, and tried the following:

```
if(icorr<0.01) {icorr <- "***"
  } else if(icorr<0.05) {icorr <- "**"
  } else if(icorr<0.1) {icorr <- "*"
  } else {icorr <- NA}
```

Definitely doesn't work. Any tips would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could use `cut`? Something like `cut(icorr, c(0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, Inf), right = F, include.lowest = T, labels = c("***", "**", "*", NA))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
  icorr <- ifelse(icorr<0.01, "***", 
                  ifelse(icorr<0.05, "**", 
                         ifelse( icorr<0.1, "*", NA)))
```

If this does not work, please provide a reproducable example.

Note that `ifelse` is a vectorized version of `if`. That is, if you want to do something to a whole vector, `ifelse` is probably preferred to `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You should tell R to select the rows that fit your conditions.

So, for instance:

```
 icorr[icorr < 0.01] <- "***"
```

This works because `icorr<0.01` returns an array of `TRUE` and `FALSE`, with which you can index your array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `findInterval`

```
icorr <- c(0.002, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.1, 0.2, 0.02, 0.3, 0.03,0.049)
c("***","**", "*", NA)[findInterval(icorr, c(-Inf,0.01, 0.05, 0.1, Inf))]
#[1] "***" "*"   "*"   "*"   NA    NA    "**"  NA    "**"  "**"
```